# powershell how to remove broken symlink

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\> cmd /c mklink /d testlink non-existent-dir
symbolic link created for testlink <<===>> non-existent-dir
PS C:\> rm .\testlink
Remove-Item : C:\testlink is a NTFS junction point. Use the Force parameter to delete or modify.
At line:1 char:3
+ rm <<<<  .\testlink
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\testlink:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotEmpty,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

PS C:\> rm -force .\testlink
Remove-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\testlink'.
At line:1 char:3
+ rm <<<<  -force .\testlink
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\testlink:String) [Remove-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

PS C:\>
```

The error is related to the fact that rm -force tries to remove items inside wherever the link is pointing. How can I remove this thing using the command line? Where can I report powershell/shell bugs? It seems powershell is not on ms connect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
cmd /c rmdir testlink
```

`cmd` doesn't know about `rm`

Comment: Works, now where could let MS know about this bug?

Comment: PS doesn't have `mklink` yet so it makes sense that it doesn't know how to deal with broken ones. I'd call it a "feature request" rather than a "bug". I would imagine it's already on the roadmap. Here's a link for feedback, however: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell

Comment: thanks. Don't know how I missed the ms connect link before.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mountvol /d command

List the GUID:

PS C:> Mountvol

then

PS C:> mountvol \?\Volume{2eca078d-5cbc-43d3-aff8-7e8511f60d0e}\ /d

replacing the relevant GUID in the above

Comment: There's no indication of which volume corresponds to the broken symlink I want to delete.

Comment: I havent tried it yet, but I dont think that matters, just run 'mountvol' on the server and it should list all the mount points on all the volumes (along with their GUIDs)

Answer (score 1):

I use .net from powershell to do this

```
[System.IO.Directory]::Delete($Path,$true)
```

Where $Path is equal to the path of your symlink. rmdir does not provide consistent result and will almost always return an error when run from powershell, regardless if it was successful or not.